# View Controller Doesn't Conform To Protocol AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm trying to make a camera that can record video, and I need AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate to make it work but for somer reason it's saying...

Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate'.

I have this above my class title, but still doesn't fix the problem...

```
class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
}
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")

    }
}
```

Here's all my code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import MobileCoreServices
import AVFoundation

class VideoDelegate : NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL outputFileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) {
    println("capture output : finish recording to \(outputFileURL)")
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL fileURL: NSURL!, fromConnections connections: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("capture output: started recording to \(fileURL)")

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?
var videoCaptureOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()    // var videoCaptureOutputF = AVCaptureFileOutput()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
    for device in devices {

        if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back {
                captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                if captureDevice != nil {
                    beginSession()
                }

            }

        }

    }

}

func beginSession() {
    var err : NSError? = nil
    captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice, error: &err))
    if err != nil {
        println("Error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }
    videoCaptureOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    //videoCaptureOutput.sampleBufferDelegate=self
    videoCaptureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    captureSession.addOutput(videoCaptureOutput)
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.bounds.width,  self.view.bounds.height)
    var startVideoBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(10,40, 40, 40))
    startVideoBtn.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
    startVideoBtn.addTarget(self, action: "startVideoRecording", forControlEvents:
        UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(startVideoBtn)
    var stopVideoBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(200, 40, 40, 40))
    stopVideoBtn.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
    stopVideoBtn.addTarget(self, action: "stopVideoRecording", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(stopVideoBtn)
}
func startVideoRecording(){
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
func stopVideoRecording(){
    captureSession.stopRunning()
    print(videoCaptureOutput)

    // here i am getting problems that how to save recorded   video
    let videoDelegate = VideoDelegate()
    let fileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    // captureSession.addOutput(videoCaptureOutput)
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString
    let outputPath = "\(documentsPath)/output.mp4"
    let outputFileUrl = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath)
    fileOutput.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(outputFileUrl, recordingDelegate: videoDelegate)

    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting it or how to fix it. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewController` doesn't conform to the protocol, which is why you're getting the warning. It looks like `VideoDelegate` does, not `ViewController`.

To resolve, either move that stuff to `ViewController`, or set your capture delegate to an instance of `VideoDelegate` instead of `ViewController`.

Comment: I edited my post so it's all of my code. Could you show me what you mean because I'm kind of confused on what I should do?

Comment: `ViewController` doesn't implement the method required by the protocol you specified. You are promising to implement the method in the `ViewController` class and then failing to do so. This is why the compiler is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the exact same issue and if I find out the way, I'll put the answer.. I took a look inside your code nd you need to remove "AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate"  and  "AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate" from you ViewController, this is because you are not implementing the methods of each delegate.

Your videoDelegate class is ok.. there, you are implementing correctly the methods of AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate.

so

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
```

instead of

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you haven't included the compulsory function that you need to include when you call this protocol. Add these functions at the bottom of your code(Swift 3):

```
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {
    //Show User recording has started
}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
    print("Finished \(error)")
    //Save Video to Camera Roll
    if error == nil{
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
    }
}
```